# redirect .php and .html to extensionless version

Tags: .htaccess

I have pages like domain.de/test and I want every other version to redirect to this:

- www.domain.de/test
- List itemdomain.de/test.php
- domain.de/test/
- (and mixed forms of those)

How can I solve this? I found solutions for every version except to remove the file-extension. But of course the image and pdf file extensions should work.

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bm-translations.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
## Enable gzip compression ##
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
## END Enable gzip compression ##
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

AddType font/woff .woff
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff

AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 3 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 3 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

And is there a way to combine those rules somehow to reduce code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: thats no answer to my question. I already removed the need for file-extension but want a redirect but only for .php and .html so images and pdf are still available

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566026/1427878 to the duplicate already does that for the `.php` extension.

Comment: I tried several answers, but none of them are working with my .htaccess from above @Cbroe
.php is still accessable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following htaccess  (The shorter  version of your RewriteRules) .I also added rules to remove .php extension from urls.

```
 RewriteEngine on

 #http to https and www to non-www in a single redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bm-translations.de/$1 [L,R=301]
# remove php extension
# redirect/ /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R]
#rewrite /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
## Enable gzip compression ##
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
## END Enable gzip compression ##
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

AddType font/woff .woff
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff

AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 3 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 3 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Thank you very much but now its redirecting to extensionless but this is now resulting in 404 error

Comment: @KrystianManthey Does the file uri you are accessing  exist in your file system?  Is it an existing .php file?

Comment: yes all existing subpages are ending with .php and with your code all are redirected to the version without php. But this is then not working.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in  htaccess?

Comment: same problem. I will contact my hoster, maybe its some server-side configuration problem?

Comment: Yes maybe so. because the rule is working as expected on my server.